# Python Nested Obj to JSON

Tags: python, json

How can I get JSON from nested python object

class simplobj:

```
 def _init_(self,fname,lname,depart):
       self.fname=fname
       self.lname=lname
       self.depart = depart
```

class jsonobj:

```
  array = [] 
  def _init_(self,time,listOfSimpleObj):
       self.time = time
       self.array = listofSimpleObj
```

class Main:

```
  listOfSimpleObj =[]
  sobj = simplobj("fname1","lname1","depart1")
  listOfSimpleObj.append(sobj)
  outputjsonobj = jsonobj(time,listOfSimpleObj)
  output = json.dumps(outputjsonobj._dict_)



output: { "time" : "time", "array":  [ 
{ "fname": "fname1", "lname": "lname1", "depart": "depart1"},
{ "fname": "fname2", "lname": "lname2", "depart": "depart2"},
{ "fname": "fname3", "lname": "lname3", "depart": "depart3"}  ] }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the JSON output you've shown?

Comment: not getting required output ; error  result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)    ..... jsonStr = json.dumps(sendobj.__dict__)   raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

Comment: For future posts, please include the actual code. The above has typos (`_init_` and `listofSimpleObj`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `json.JSONEncoder` to specify how your classes should be serialized:

```py
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, simplobj) or isinstance(obj, jsonobj):
            return obj.__dict__
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

...

output = json.dumps(outputjsonobj, cls=MyEncoder)
```